# TypeError: Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a Dataframe which stores Australian City names and count of cases / per city. I am trying to run it; I however get an error

```
import folium
import pandas as pd

# Make a data frame with dots to show on the map
data = pd.DataFrame({
   'lat':[-58, 2, 145],
   'lon':[-34, 49, -38],
   'name':['Sydney', 'Melbourne', 'Brisbane'],
   'value':[4,3,2]

})
data

# Make an empty map
m = folium.Map(location=[20,0], tiles="Mapbox Bright", zoom_start=2)

for i in range(0,len(data)):
   folium.Circle(
      location=[data.iloc[i]['lon'], data.iloc[i]['lat']],
      popup=data.iloc[i]['name'],
      radius=data.iloc[i]['value']*10000,
      color='crimson',
      fill=True,`enter code here`
      fill_color='crimson'
   ).add_to(m)

m.save('mymap.html')
```

TypeError: Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like an issue with the Folium library - one quick solution is to change your ints to floats - otherwise you can try using the numpy library to change to your ints from int64 to int8, etc.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
   'lat':[-58.0, 2.0, 145.0],
   'lon':[-34.0, 49.0, -38.0],
   'name':['Sydney', 'Melbourne', 'Brisbane'],
   'value':[4.0,3.0,2.0]

})
```